# How to create a BsonDocument from stream (c#)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mimekit

I want to insert an email read from a server to a MongoDB. I use MimeKit to get the emails from the server. Trying to insert it directly `mimeMessage.ToBsonDocument()` I get `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Timeouts are not supported on this stream.'` So I'm guessing that the message object uses an internal stream to read the data from the server.

I now want to use a memory stream to first write the data to a stream and then create a BsonDocument from that stream.

I read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/xoC2iWiCRvQ) that the best way to do this is with `BsonDocument.ReadFrom(ms);` but the compiler cannot find the method 'ReadFrom' in BsonDocument.

Was this method replaced in newer versions? With what?
Or what is the best way to create a BsonDocument from a stream?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation at http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.0/html/Methods_T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument.htm, it seems you need to convert the stream into a string and then use the `Parse()` method:

```
string bsonText;
using (var reader = new StreamReader (ms))
    bsonText = reader.ReadToEnd ();

var bsonDocument = BsonDocument.Parse (bsonText);
```

That said, I don't think that you can just write the `MimeMessage` to a stream and then expect to parse that into a `BsonDocument`. When you write a `MimeMessage` to a stream, it will be in MIME format, not BSON format.